# The use of packages to parse command arguments employing options/switches?

Tags: tcl

I have a couple questions about adding options/switches (with and without parameters) to procedures/commands. I see that `tcllib` has `cmdline` and Ashok Nadkarni's book on Tcl recommends the `parse_args` package and states that using Tcl to handle the arguments is much slower than this package using C.  The [Nov. 2016 paper on parse_args](https://www.tcl-lang.org/community/tcl2016/assets/talk33/parse_args-paper.pdf) states that Tcl script methods are or can be 50 times slower.

1. Are Tcl methods really signicantly slower? Is there some minimum threshold number of options to be reached before using a package?
2. Is there any reason to use `parse_args` (not in tcllib) over `cmdline` (in tcllib)?
3. Can both be easily included in a starkit?
4. Is this included in 8.7a now? (I'd like to use 8.7a but I'm using Manjaro Linux and am afraid that adding it outside the package manager will cause issues that I won't know how to resolve or even just "undo").

Thank you for considering my questions.

Comment: Could you give some examples of "options/switches (with and without parameters)" that you are interested in? What does "with/ without parameters" mean, exactly?

Comment: I've never heard of this `parse_args` package, but `cmdline` works fine.

Comment: @mrcalvin Perhaps I'm not using the right terminology; but by "without parameters" I'm referring to something like `-nocase` and "with parameters" `-length` which requires an accompanying value.

Comment: @Shawn Thanks. I should've added the [link to parse_args](https://github.com/RubyLane/parse_args) which I got from Nadkarni's book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Are Tcl methods really signicantly slower? Is there some minimum threshold number of options to be reached before using a package?

Potentially. Procedures have overhead to do with managing the stack frame and so on, and code implemented in C can avoid a number of overheads due to the way values are managed in current Tcl implementations. The difference is much more profound for numeric code than for string-based code, as the cost of boxing and unboxing numeric values is quite significant (strings are always boxed in all languages).

As for which is the one to use, it really depends on the details as you are trading off flexibility for speed. I've never known it be a problem for command line parsing.

(If you ask me, fifty options isn't really that many, except that it's quite a lot to pass on an actual command line. It might be easier to design a configuration file format — perhaps a simple Tcl script! — and then to just pass the name of that in as the actual argument.)

> 2. Is there any reason to use parse_args (not in tcllib) over cmdline (in tcllib)?

Performance? Details of how you describe things to the parser?

> 3. Can both be easily included in a starkit?

As long as any C code is built with Tcl stubs enabled (typically not much more than define `USE_TCL_STUBS` and link against the stub library) then it can go in a starkit as a loadable library. Using the stubbed build means that the compiled code doesn't assume exactly which version of the Tcl library is present or what its path is; those are assumptions that are usually wrong with a starkit.

Tcl-implemented packages can always go in a starkit. Hybrid packages need a little care for their C parts, but are otherwise pretty easy.

Many packages either always build in stubbed mode or have a build configuration option to do so.

> 4. Is this included in 8.7a now? (I'd like to use 8.7a but I'm using Manjaro Linux and am afraid that adding it outside the package manager will cause issues that I won't know how to resolve or even just "undo").

We think we're about a month from the feature freeze for 8.7, and builds seem stable in automated testing so the beta phase will probably be fairly short. The list of what's in can be found [here](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tips/doc/trunk/index.md) (filter for *8.7* and *Final*). However, bear in mind that we tend to feel that if code can be done in an extension then there's usually no desperate need for it to be in Tcl itself.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and link. I asked about 8.7 because of https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.7/TclLib/ParseArgs.html.